# Tell CMake to use custom Find*.cmake instead of system wide one

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I wanna use the KWayland library which I compiled from source and installed in a folder. I want my other project to use that. But instead, it uses the one installed system-wide as a dependency of KDE by the package manager.

I tried setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/path/to/my/cmakefiles;/usr` in QtCreator and reconfigured the project, but it still uses the one in `/usr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for an example package `ABC` will look for a **package configuration file**, which will have one of the following forms for package `ABC`:

- `abc-config.cmake`
- `ABCConfig.cmake`

By setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, it does *not* tell CMake to look elsewhere for a find module (e.g.: `FindABC.cmake`).

If you installed your package `ABC` (in your case, KWayland), the installed package should have provided a package configuration file you can use. So point the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to this file instead:

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /path/to/KWayland/package/config/files
```

---

If **no** package configuration file was provided, you could use a find module (`FindABC.cmake`) instead to import the package into your project. To tell CMake to look in a non-default location for find modules, you need to update the [`CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) variable instead:

```
CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: /path/to/my/cmakefiles
```